# Got a mobile app that pulls JSON data from from my server, how do I secure this connection?

Tags: json, api, rest, security, mobile

I'm developing a website and mobile application that communicate with each other.

It's very basic at the moment: the app makes a get request to a URL and the server returns JSON data.

I want to secure this and make sure no-one can send a get request to the URL and get this data (only the website and the app). Is it ok to make a 60+ character password that the app can send with the request that the server accepts before data is sent, or is this breakable?

I dont want to use OAuth because it's overkill as only the app and the site are going to communicate. Please provide me with a few solutions, thanks!

Comment: once the app is out there, assume that your password/key/whatever is public knowledge.  If you need to secure the data, you have to authenticate your users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTTPS to transmit data.But you will need an SSL cerificate for this.